# why does the checkbox go down?

Tags: html, css

I have this html and css code, how come if I click on "Yes" the "No" checkbox goes down?
I would like that when I click on the "Yes" checkbox the "No" checkbox remains in line with the "Yes" checkbox

```css
fieldset {
  width: 920px;
  border: 2px ridge green;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

legend {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#n {
  display: none;
}

#y {
  display: none;
}

#m:checked~#n {
  display: block;
}

#a:checked~#y {
  display: block;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Have you a car? </legend>
    <label for="m">Yes</label>
    <input id="m" type="checkbox">
    <nav id="n">
      <ul>
        <li>ok</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <label for="y">No</label>
    <input id="a" type="checkbox">
    <nav id="y">
      <ul>
        <li> ops</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Rather than checkboxes, I think they should be radio selects, as it's a Yes / No response, not one that could possible have both selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the nav so there is not a block element between the checkboxes

Also make them radios:

```css
fieldset {
  width: 920px;
  border: 2px ridge green;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

legend {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#n {
  display: none;
}

#y {
  display: none;
}

#m:checked~#n {
  display: block;
}

#a:checked~#y {
  display: block;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Have you a car? </legend>
    <label for="m">Yes</label>
    <input id="m" type="radio" name="car">
    <label for="y">No</label>
    <input id="a" type="radio" name="car">
    <nav id="y">
      <ul>
        <li> ops</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <nav id="n">
      <ul>
        <li>ok</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you set `display:block` when showing the `nav`. Use `inline-block` or `inline` If you want the `nav` to be on the same line with the checkboxes . Also add `margin:0` to the `ul` to overwrite the default margin of the list.

```css
fieldset {
  width: 920px;
  border: 2px ridge green;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

legend {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#n {
  display: none;
}

#y {
  display: none;
}

#m:checked~#n {
  display: inline-block;
}

#a:checked~#y {
  display: inline-block;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;

}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  }
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Have you a car? </legend>
    <label for="m">Yes</label>
    <input id="m" type="checkbox">
    <nav id="n">
      <ul>
        <li>ok</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <label for="y">No</label>
    <input id="a" type="checkbox">
    <nav id="y">
      <ul>
        <li> ops</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You used `nav`, `ul`, `li`, all are block-level elements. You can make your html markup better or if you want to stick with this markup, make your `nav`, `ul`, `li` display inline.

```
<nav id="n">
    <ul>
      <li>ok</li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
```

```
#m:checked~#n,#n ul, #n li {
  display: inline;
}
```

Or you can use only `nav` there and remove the `ul`, `li`

```
<nav id="n">
    ok
 </nav>
```

```
#m:checked~#n{
  display: inline;
}
```

The best idea is to change your html markup and make it better like this.

```
 <span id="n">
    ok
 </span>
```

```
#m:checked~#n{
  display: inline;
}
```